# 'Watch' as a noun vs imperative. Are they connected for native speakers?

Tags: psychology, psycholinguistics

Well, this question originates from a redesign of Apple Watch ad.

Original poster has a slogan

> The Watch is here

One guy offered that

> Watch here

would have added more pun.

[image: https://scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/t31.0-8/11026223_10206197977942353_4293797260373063317_o.jpg]

But I am not sure whether `watch` used as a verb in a short phrase is ever perceived by a native speaker as a noun?

Comment: I'm surprised that Apple didn't go with "Watch different."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not normally, but there are contexts when it might be. For example, in a hurriedly written note, or a text message.

So, in the context of the ad, some people would certainly get the pun. Perhaps most, because *watch here* as a command is rather unlikely (*watch* most often takes a direct object, and when it doesn't the implied object is usually very obvious, so *here* will be unnecessary) so I suspect people would be looking for a reason why the writer had used an unlikely sequence of words.